# Extracting Coordinates from PDB file

Tags: perl, file, pdb

To extract the Atom lines from PDB file i have written the code bellow which is not showing any outputfile when i run the program

```
print" Enter the file name";

$a=<>;

@arr=split(" ",$a);

if($i=0; $i< scalar @arr; $i++)

foreach $values(@arr)
{

    if($values=~/^ATOM/)
    {
        print FH1 $a;

        open(FH1,">>output.pdb")
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not opening a file for reading anywhere in that code.

Comment: @Mat, you don't have to open the magic ARGV filehandle explicitly.  The real problem is that his code doesn't even compile.  That first `if` looks like it was meant to be a `for`.  It also lacks braces, which aren't optional in Perl.

Comment: @cjm: I don't think that `foreach $values(@arr)` does any kind of magic, I don't see how ARGV filehandle could be use anywhere in that code. Am I missing something? (Except for `$a=<>;` of course.)

Comment: @Mat, that is what I was referring to.  But it's hard to tell what he expects the program to do, since it won't even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use split with PDB text files since the fields are defined by position and not by separators. See [Coordinate File Description (PDB Format)](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html).

Instead, you should use `substr ($line,$start,$len)` with different values of `$start` and `$len` for each field (taken from the [Coordinate File Description](http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html)), or rely on one of the available PDB parsers, such as [Bioperl's](http://doc.bioperl.org/releases/bioperl-current/bioperl-live/Bio/Structure/IO/pdb.html).